# .NET SQL Server Trace with Filter

Tags: .net, sql-server, trace

I've seen http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/26/receiving-profiler-events.aspx as well as https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345134%28v=sql.90%29.aspx as well as numerous other posts on SO and on the web, yet I could not find a any resource which indicates how to create a SQL Server trace in .NET with a filter, say by spid, sql object, or otherwise, that would allow me to only trace those events.  How can this be done?

Thanks,